# WebView не грузит изображения

Tags: android, webview, изображения

Есть собственно WebView и html-код лежащий в string. Текст грузится отлично, но изображения просто не видно. Подозреваю что допускаю ошибку в написании пути до изображения, но при вызове loadUrl("путь_до_картинки"); все грузится. Ниже код из string и вызов.

Вызов:

```
itemView.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, getString(R.string.pagehistory), "text/html", "utf-8", null);
```

И код:

```
<string name="pagehistory">
    <html>
        <body>
            <p align="center">
                <img src="file:///android_res/raw/history.png"/><br/>
                текст_текст_ТЕКСТ
            </p>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

перенесите изображения в assets

Comment: Все так же, в assets они лежали изначально. Возможно проблема именно в том что данный адрес понятен loadurl но не понятен в контексте html.

Comment: думаю да - делал просто файл html - загружал из assets,  все работало  отлично

Comment: Так тоже делал, однако кодировка ломалась ужасно и не чинилась совсем.

Comment: Может можно как то подгружать данные в webView?

Answer (score 0):

**Activity**:

```
mWebViev = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.wv);
mWebViev.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/fileone.html");
```

**fileone.html**, который лежит в `assets`:

```
<html>
<body>
    <img src="img.png" width = "300">
</body>
</html>
```

**img.png** также лежит в `assets`.

Comment: А теперь попробуйте написать текст и посмотрите что будет с кириллицей.

Comment: кодировку файла поставьте utf-8, проверено )

Comment: <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
</head>

Увы. При этом текст не читаем уже в браузере. Если поставить win-1251 тоже самое.

Comment: @nekaneka, а вы уверены, что сам файл в UTF-8 сохранён? Судя по тому, что вы рассказываете, это не так.

Comment: Рукалицо. Спасибо большое, как обычно самое очевидное.